# How to import and build with a group of local modules in Go

Tags: go, go-modules

I have the following files :

```
$GOPATH/src/example.com
├── a
│   ├── a.go
│   └── go.mod
├── b
│   ├── b.go
│   └── go.mod
└── c
    ├── go.mod
    └── main.go
```

Contents are :

`a/a.go` :

```golang
package a

func NewA() int {
    return 1
}
```

`a/go.mod` :

```golang
module example.com/a

go 1.17
```

`b/b.go` :

```golang
package b

import A "example.com/a"

func NewB() int {
    return A.NewA()
}
```

`b/go.mod` :

```golang
module example.com/b

go 1.17

replace example.com/a => ../a

require example.com/a v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 // indirect
```

`c/main.go` :

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import B "example.com/b"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(B.NewB())
}
```

`c/go.mod` :

```golang
module example.com/c

go 1.17

replace example.com/b => ../b

require example.com/b v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 // indirect
```

When `go run main.go` in the `c` directory I get :

```
../b/b.go:3:8: missing go.sum entry for module providing package example.com/a (imported by example.com/b); to add:
        go get example.com/b@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
```

And `go get example.com/b@v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000` says :

```
go: downloading example.com/a v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000
example.com/b imports
        example.com/a: unrecognized import path "example.com/a": reading https://example.com/a?go-get=1: 404 Not Found
```

For sure this is a local package and not available on internet, and it use `replace` in all necessary `go.mod` files.

How to work with local packages?

If I rename `example.com` to `example` I get : `missing dot in first path element`.

Comment: This looks like it should be 1 module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from [Go Modules Reference: `replace` directive:](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace)

> `replace` directives only apply in the main module’s `go.mod` file and are ignored in other modules. See [Minimal version selection](https://golang.org/ref/mod#minimal-version-selection) for details.

The `replace` directive in `b/go.mod` has no effect when you build the main package / module. You must add that `replace` directive to the main module's `go.mod`.

So add it to `c/go.mod`. After running `go mod tidy` in the `c` folder, it'll look like this:

```
module example.com/c

go 1.17

replace example.com/b => ../b

replace example.com/a => ../a

require example.com/b v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000

require example.com/a v0.0.0-00010101000000-000000000000 // indirect
```

Without this `replace` in `c/go.mod` you were seeing the error message because the go tool tried to get the package from `example.com` (which is an existing domain) but it does not contain a go module.